# What is best way to clean up my contact lists that are synced between Android and Gmail?

Tags: contacts, settings, sync, google-contacts

Most all of my contacts in gmail have been duplicated (sync issue?) and I also have quite a few outdated contacts to delete. I just figured out how to 'reverse' sync from my phone to gmail which has made an even bigger mess.

I'd like to end up with a nice clean list that is synced 100% between my gmail and my phone, with no duplicates and only current contacts.

What is the best (fastest?) way to do this?  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

In your android/contacts select only to show contacts from your google account.
You can easily delete your duplicate contacts from your gmail/google account. There is a button on the left side in google contacts for that purpose only.
after deleting contacts recognised by google as duplicate, you can sync your contacts and all your duplicate contacts be gone.